# Dimension Changes Based on Source to Dimension Value Comparison

Tags: ssis, scd2

am using the Kimball SCD Component in SSIS.  I would like to be able to direct rows to the type 1 or type 2 paths based on a comparison of the current dimension value to the source data, i.e., if a date in the source is less than the corresponding current date in the dimension, then type 2 else type 1.

Has anyone done any of this type of data comparisons?  I've considered using a trigger, but the performance hit would probable be huge.

It seems like a splitter would work, but I don't see where I can evaluate values of the two data streams.

Thanks,